# How to set invisible false only a charator of a string using js or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, invisible

I am having a string

`"Custormer1#-#Project1".`

I want to invisible the two #s in the string? Can I do this without replacing the character using javascript or JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have is to wrap them in a `<span>`-element and hide that span with CSS.

Check this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CJefw/ and note that the text() method in jquery still returns the right content, without the added spans.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery with `map` the original string array and in the map you can ignore the char.

so the original string wont be affected

that way - you wont replace the chars....